# What is the ratio of speed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

If two trains start at same time from point A and B towards each other and after crossing they take |a| and |b| seconds in reaching B and A respectively.

What is the ratio of speed of A and B.

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange. You should provide your own approaches when asking a question, no matter if those approaches produced any (partial) solution or even a wrong "solution". We would like to see what you have done.

Comment: If total initial distance between A and B is x meter and let's they meet at d distance away from A and x-d distance away from B.Let's their speed is S1 and S2 then   aS1+bS2=x . and d/S2=b and (x-d)/S1=a ,but i couldn't find the ratio from these.please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose speed of $A$ and $B$ is $s_1$ and $s_2$.
time taken to meet is $t$.
and total distance between $A$ and $B$ is $x$.
Then:

$s_1(t) + s_2(t)=x$  $......$equation $(1)$

$s_1(t+a) =x$    $......$equation$(2)$

$s_2(t+b)=x$    $......$equation$(3)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$s_1(t)+s_2(t)=s_1(t)+s_1(a)$

So: $s_2(t)=s_1(a)$

which implies that: $\frac{s_1}{s_2} = \frac{t}{a}$   $......$equation$(4)$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$:

$$s_1(t)+s_2(t)=s_2(t) +s_2(b)$$

So: $s_1(t)=s_2(b)$

which implies that: $\frac{s_1}{s_2}=\frac{b}{t}$ $......$equation$(5)$

So, from equations $(4)$ and $(5)$:

$$\frac{t}{a}=\frac{b}{t}\rightarrow t^2=b\times a\rightarrow t=\sqrt{ba}$$

Now we can easily find ratio by putting value of $t$ in equation $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$\frac{s_1}{s_2}=\frac{\sqrt b}{\sqrt a}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Yes, this is correct.  Was that your question, or did you find this after posting the question?  If you have a solution that you would like people to check, you should include it in the question.  Also, there's a better way when you want to label equations.  Search for "tags and reference" in this [MathJaxTutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: When no one answered it ,i tried and finally i got succss ,that's why i posted the solution as well.